# how to use html div tags in php

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to loop the entire html div part so that it creates 12 columns(twitter-bootstrap) through div tags.
In this case it shows that variable 'dep' is undefined..

```
 <? php
$q1="select * from product limit 12";
$ret=mysqli_query($mysqli,$q1);
while($dep=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ret)){
    ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="single-products">
                                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                <?php   echo "<img     src=\"images/home/".$dep['product_image']."\" alt='".$dep['product_name']."' />";
                                    echo "<h2>".$dep['product_price']."</h2>";
                                    echo "<p>".$dep['product_name']."</p>";
                                    ?>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>";
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-overlay">
                                    <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <?php   echo "<h2>".$dep['product_price']."</h2>";
                                        echo "<p>".$dep['product_name']."</p>"; 
                                        ?>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="choose">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to wishlist</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to compare</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
 }
                    ?>
```

I also tried this kind of format too,but it only displayed the echo keywords.In this case it displays the echo tags as if they were a part of html itself

```
  <? php
$q1="select * from product";
$ret=mysqli_query($mysqli,$q1);
while($dep=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ret)){

                    echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
                        echo '<div class="product-image-wrapper">';
                            echo '<div class="single-products">';
                                echo '<div class="productinfo text-center">';
                                    echo "<img src=\"images/home/".$dep['product_image']."\" alt='".$dep['product_name']."' />";
                                    echo "<h2>".$dep['product_price']."</h2>";
                                    echo "<p>".$dep['product_name']."</p>";
                                    echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-default add-to-cart\"><i class=\"fa fa-shopping-cart\"></i>Add to cart</a>";
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "<div class=\"product-overlay\">";
                                    echo "<div class=\"overlay-content\">";
                                        echo "<h2>".$dep['product_price']."</h2>";
                                        echo "<p>".$dep['product_name']."</p>";
                                        echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"btn btn-default add-to-cart\"><i class=\"fa fa-shopping-cart\"></i>Add to cart</a>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "<div class=\"choose\">";
                                echo "<ul class=\"nav nav-pills nav-justified\">";
                                    echo "<li><a href=\"\"><i class=\"fa fa-plus-square\"></i>Add to wishlist</a></li>";
                                    echo"<li><a href=\"\"><i class=\"fa fa-plus-square\"></i>Add to compare</a></li>";
                                echo "</ul>";
                            echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
}
                    ?>
```

I cannot understand where am i going wrong.Please help..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are a lot of ways to do this. What errors are you getting or what is "going wrong"?

Comment: maybe to change 'mysqli_fetch_assoc' to 'mysqli_fetch_array'?

Comment: Since you say it's displaying the echo tags as if they were part of html, i think all that's wrong in the second example is   <? php instead of <?php (the extra space). <? is a php short tag, but it could be disabled on your machine. The other error "'dep' is undefined.." might mean that there were 0 results from the query.

Comment: @billirichards- yeah it was the space between <? and php that produced the error. Thanx. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
$q1 = "select * from product";
$ret = mysqli_query($mysqli,$q1);
$html = "";
while($dep=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ret)){
     $html .= "\t<div class='col-sm-4'>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t<div class='product-image-wrapper'>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t<div class='single-products'>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t<div class='productinfo text-center'>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t<img src='images/home/{$dep['product_image']}' alt='{$dep['product_name']}' />\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t<h2>{$dep['product_price']}</h2>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t<p>{$dep['product_name']}</p>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t<a href='#' class='btn btn-default add-to-cart'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i>Add to cart</a>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t<div class='product-overlay'>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t<div class='overlay-content'>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t<h2>{$dep['product_price']}</h2>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t<p>{$dep['product_name']}</p>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href='#' class='btn btn-default add-to-cart'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i>Add to cart</a>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t</div>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t<div class='choose'>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t<ul class='nav nav-pills nav-justified'>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-plus-square'></i>Add to wishlist</a></li>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-plus-square'></i>Add to compare</a></li>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t\t</ul>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t\t</div>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t\t</div>\r\n";
     $html .= "\t</div>\r\n";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Found 2 syntax errors, the `<? php` and one `echo"..."`. The echo syntax may get overlooked by PHP in the end, but I noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your second code has a space between the `<?` and `php` otherwise they are essentially the same thing. Or perhaps it was a formatting issue?